# Load and save a file to server trough HTTP POST request

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to send a photo from `/MNT/SDCARD` or `ASSETS/FILES` folder from an android app. I am getting those type of errors :

```
05-12 16:15:15.468: E/AndroidRuntime(17228): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.app_flower3/files/qqqwww.png (No such file or directory)

05-12 16:15:15.468: E/AndroidRuntime(17228):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)


05-12 16:39:20.417: E/AndroidRuntime(19575): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File //mnt//sdcard//gauss.jpg contains a path separator
```

This is my code :

```
public Map<String,String> postSendImageAndGetJson() throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException 
{
    File rootPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Log.d("CILO",rootPath.getPath().toString());

    printer.log("CHESTIE!!");
    // Create map
    Map<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>();


    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(context.openFileInput("//mnt//sdcard//gauss.jpg"));
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    String upload_url = "http://www.aplicatii-iphone.ro/android/test.php"; // HARDCODED
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(upload_url); // HARDCODED
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    //Set Data and Content-type header for the image
    entity.addPart("file",
    new ByteArrayBody(data, "image/jpeg", "file"));
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);
    try 
    {
         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        //Read the response
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("CILO", "after uploading file "+ jsonString);

    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return map;
}
```

1. Where do i make the mistake?
2. I have searched on the internet, where do i find a good tutorial about working with data on an android app (images).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays in this line: `BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(context.openFileInput("//mnt//sdcard//gauss.jpg"));`  Using this method of opening a file uses Android's internal file storage-- a directory created for your app which only your app has access to.  To open a file stored on the SD Card, use something like this:

```
File dirSD = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder_name");
File sdFile = new File(dirSD , "somefilename.txt");
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String content = "";
    String buffer;
    while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {
        content += buffer + "\n"
    }
    br.close();
}
```

This is how I would do it for a text file; since it looks like you're dealing with an image, you'll probably want to do it differently (e.g. not use a string to store the contents of the file).  There is definitely [example code already on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821478/android-get-images-from-sdcard)

Comment: `BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new InputStream(sdFile));` this gives me error, `BufferedInputStream` constructor only accept `InputStream` object, do you have a complete code please? Thank you.

Comment: check out the edits I made, hopefully should clear it up. Good luck